# RefreshApex is not working with data table infinite loading

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom

I've created a data table and used infinite scrolling & used an offset to get a set of value from backend. but refresh apex is not working with it as the wire data reference changes once new value is retrieved from the apex .

HTML

```
<div class="data-table slds-hide" style="height: 20rem;">
        <lightning-datatable
            key-field="id"
            data={data}
            show-row-number-column
            enable-infinite-loading="true"
            onloadmore={loadMoreData}
            onrowaction={handleRowAction}
            row-number-offset={rowOffset}
            hide-checkbox-column
            columns={columns}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
```

JS

```
@wire(getRecords, { sObjectName: '$objectName' , offSet: '$offSetValue'})
    recordsData(result)
    {
        this.recordData = result;
        const { error, data } = result;
        if (data) {
            if (!this.offSetValue) {                
                this.data = data.objectData.Records;
                if(this.data) this.totalRecords = this.data.length;
                if (!data.objectData.Records) {
                    const dataTable = this.template.querySelector(`lightning-datatable`);
                    if(dataTable) dataTable.isLoading = false;
                }
                this.columns = JSON.parse(data.objectData.columns);
                this.columns.push({
                    type: 'action',
                    typeAttributes: {
                        rowActions: this.getRowActions,
                        menuAlignment: 'right',
                    }
                })
                console.log('Columns JSON>>', JSON.stringify(this.columns));
                this.template.querySelector('div').classList.remove('slds-hide');
                this.spinner = false;
            }
            if (this.offSetValue) {
                console.log('Inside offset value');
                const dataTable = this.template.querySelector(`lightning-datatable`);
                const currentData = this.data;
                this.data = this.data.concat(data.objectData.Records);
                this.loadMoreStatus = '';
                this.totalRecords = this.data.length;
                if (this.data.length >= this.maxRows) {
                    dataTable.enableInfiniteLoading = false;
                    this.loadMoreStatus = 'No more data to load';
                }
                dataTable.isLoading = false;
            }
            if (this.totalRecords < this.offSetValue) {
                console.log('total records>>', this.totalRecords);
                this.loadMoreStatus = 'No more records to load';
                const dataTable = this.template.querySelector(`lightning-datatable`);
                if(dataTable) dataTable.isLoading = false;
            }
        }
        else if (error) {
            console.log('Error in wire record',JSON.stringify(error));
        }
        else if (!data) {
            const dataTable = this.template.querySelector(`lightning-datatable`);
            if(dataTable) dataTable.isLoading = false;
            //this.loadMoreStatus = 'No more data to load';
        }
    }
```

after update JS

```
handleSuccess(event)
    {
        refreshApex(this.recordData)
        const toastEVent = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success!',
            message: 'This Record Has Been Updated',
            variant:'Success'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(toastEVent);
        this.bShowModal = false;
        this.isEdit = false;
    }
```

Comment: I would think you want to remember the "recordData" as a map of wire results keyed on the offset, right? After all, you need to refresh every offset response, not just the most recent one.

Comment: Yup that would be correct. I would want to remember the all results. So that user can edit anyone of them and I can use refresh apex to refresh the data table, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Instead of `this.recordData = result` you just need `this.recordData[this.offsetValue] = result` (making sure to initialize it to `{}` in the declaration) then when you want to clear the cached data iterate the `this.recordData` properties (standard JS approaches all work) and call the Apex refresh with each.

Comment: I wonder if you should, however, just use imperative Apex without caching instead...?

Comment: I used wire just to use the refreshApex feature to refresh my data table after the update as with imperative I can't refresh the data table and I tried the above approach but still could see only latest set of data in the this.recordData variable

Comment: tried to refresh the apex after looping over the object `const entries = Object.entries(this.recordData);
        console.log('Entries', entries);
        entries.forEach(value =>
        {
            refreshApex(value)
        })` but still it's not working

Comment: It is a map, not an array. Take a look [here](https://attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-iterate-objects) for example.

Comment: (You may have been trying to iterate, but perhaps `values` would be better than `entries`)